# Dropbox javascript api show error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: dropbox, typeerror

I have a problem when uploading file using dropbox api for javacript. Sometime it's done but something it shows error: "TypeError: Failed to fetch" and cannot upload. Can anyone have experience about this error? Thanks in advance.

Here is my page source in Asp.Net:

```
                    var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: 'MY_TOKEN' });

                var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-upload'); //$('#file-upload');

                var filecontent = fileInput.files[0];

                var filename = fileInput.files[0].name;//.match(/([^\\\/]+)$/)[0];


                if (fileInput.files[0].size < UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT) { // File is smaller than 150 Mb - use filesUpload API
                    dbx.filesUpload({ path: '/' + filename, contents: filecontent, mode: 'overwrite', autorename: false, mute: false })
                      .then(function (response) {
                          alert('success');
                          console.log(response);
                      })
                      .catch(function (error) {
                          alert(error.name);
                          console.error(error);
                      });
```

Comment: is the accessToken a real one ? If so change it, now ;)

Comment: yes, it's real one but this is an developer account, I forget to remove it. Thanks for your mention.

Comment: so edit your post and remove it, even if it's a developer account, anyone with bad intentions can use it and cause you troubles with your dev account :/

Comment: already approve change, thank you.

Comment: Is `TypeError: Failed to fetch` the entirety of the error output you get in the console? Please add anything else. It sounds like it may just be due to intermittent connection issues. Is your network connection unreliable, or is there anything (e.g., firewall, proxy, etc.) that may be interfering?

Comment: this error is entire message show on popup, doesn't print to the console.